# Linking two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

Even this is asked a billion times here already, none of them has worked for me.
So: I have two tables:

banhammer_bans:
[image: banhammer_bans]

and banhammer_players:
[image: banhammer_players]

What sort of query should I make that it gets the name value from the "players" table corresponding to the "player_id" and "creator_id" value? I've tried with JOINS and UNIONS but no success.

Comment: If it has been asked a billion times, it will have been answered a billion times. Either use one of those answers, or show us what you have tried that doesn't work properly

Comment: Can you post the some of the actual JOINS and UNIONS?  It helps if we know what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, I erased most of the queries, but this is one I had left.      `SELECT * FROM banhammer_bans as bb
JOIN banhammer_players as bh
ON bb.player_id = bh.id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select p.name, p.id as player_id, b.creator_id as creator_id
from banhammer_bans as b
inner join banhammer_players as p on p.id = b.player_id
```

Comment: This throws a 500 error for me. Not sure if it's because error_reporting is off?

Comment: its throwing php/script error right? 500 error means code is having some issue, not ur query. Check the logs to see what has gone wrong.

Comment: Ah, got it working, but how would I get it both the creators and players id? (It's two different IDs)

Comment: made some changes in the query

Comment: I mean, I'm trying to retrieve the both names. It's returning `array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "ayyy"
  ["player_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["creator_id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}`, the name is OK, but I would want the creator name also.

Comment: where is the creator name saved? in players tables itself?

Comment: Oh, it was in the same table as the player. But after a bit of messing around, got it working. Thanks for the help man :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
select 
     * 
from 
     banhammer_bans, banhammer_players
where
     banhammer_players.player_id = banhammer_bans.id
```

This is a kind of Join too, but it has some sort of efficiency problems.

Comment: Why the fudge would this help??? I think OP just wants a simple join

Comment: I'm really sorry, I misunderstood at first. Just edited the answer. I know it is a little late ;)